# How to check in which commit line was changed in Atom?

Tags: git, atom-editor

In Xcode I can check in which git commit codeline was changed. Is it possible in Atom, our I need to check commit by commit in SourceTree?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git line](https://atom.io/packages/git-line). Refer the documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this package git-diff as per atom recommendation

Please check atom [docs](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/version-control-in-atom/#line-diffs)